# how to populate lookup field based on other field value while inserting the records

Tags: apex, process-builder, formula-field

Could you please let me know the best way to auto populate lookup field based on other field value while inserting the records .

E.g :

1. We have a custom object and it has a lookup field for contact object
2. While inserting the records in custom object, auto populate contact lookup field value based on email address in the record

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to use Flows.**

*(Setup/App Setup/Create/Workflow & Approvals/Flows/New Flow)*

Using a Record-Triggered Flow is necessary.

- Object: *your custom object*
- Trigger: *A record is created or updated.*
- Entry Conditions: we don't need it here.

The following Toolbox Elements are needed:

Logic/ Decision:
it will check whether the email address field is populated or not -> if it is populated, the lookup field will be filled automatically, if you delete the value from the email field, the lookup field will be emptied automatically. Make sure to add Outcome conditions accordingly.

1. Outcome condition

   - Label: emailIsEmpty
   - Condition:

     | Field | Operator | Value |
     | --- | --- | --- |
     | *(Global Variables/) custom object / email field* | *Equals* | *-* |
     | {!$Record.email_address__c} | Equals | {!$GlobalConstant.EmptyString} |
2. Outcome condition

   - Label: emailIsFilled
   - Condition:

     | Field | Operator | Value |
     | --- | --- | --- |
     | *(Global Variables/) custom object / email field* | *Does Not Equal* | *-* |
     | {!$Record.email_address__c} | Does Not Equal | {!$GlobalConstant.EmptyString} |

The following two elements will connect to outcome condition:

1. **emailIsEmpty:** Data/ Update Records: this will update the lookup field of your custom object with an empty string given you have removed the value from the email field.
2. **emailIsFilled:** Data/ Get Records: this will query the contact object using your email field which will act as a secondary key (assuming the email is unique for each contact object record) and will store the contact object which the email belongs to:

   - API: *Get_Contact_object*
   - Object: *Contact*
   - Condition:

     | Field | Operator | Value |
     | --- | --- | --- |
     | *contact object / email field* | *Equals* | *(Global Variables/) custom object / email field* |
     | email_address__c | Equals | {!$Record.email_address__c} |
   - How many records to store: *Only the first record* - you have unique emails
   - How to store record data: *Automatically store all fields* - this way the whole contact record is stored
3. Data/ Update Records: this connects to element 2. and this will update the lookup field with the record Id of the previously stored contact record.

   - How to Find Records to Update and Set Their Values: *Use the domain record that triggered the flow*
   - Set Field Values:

     | Field | <- | Value |
     | --- | --- | --- |
     | *custom object / lookup field* | <- | *(Record (single) variables/) Contact from Get_Contact_object / contact record id* |
     | contact_lookup__c | <- | {{!Get_Contact_object.Id}} |

This solution works in my database.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the trigger: `before insert` for this case.

```
trigger PopulateLookupField on CustomSObject(before insert) {
for(CustomSObject a : Trigger.new) {
    List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email =:a.Email];
    if(contacts.size() > 0) {
        a.ContactId = contacts[0].Id;       
    }
}}
```

You can refer to: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro